# CPython - How to create and add a method attribute to an object with __dict__?

Tags: python, cpython

This can be a tricky question...

In short I am creating and adding a method as follows:

```
static PyObject *ret_arg(PyBVHTree *self, PyObject *arg)
{
    /* just to demonstrate */
    return arg;
}
static PyMethodDef my_meth = {"ret_arg", (PyCFunction)ret_arg, METH_O, 0};       

...
    PyObject* func = PyCFunction_New(&my_meth, my_object);
    Py_DECREF(my_object);
    PyObject_SetAttrString(my_object, "ret_arg", func);
    Py_DECREF(func);
    return my_object;
}
```

It works! But having some problems :(

**eg.:**

- If I del my_object. And use the new method, **CRASH**.
- When I close the program with python. Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. And this is no problem with refcount

So my question is:

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I don't know the Python C API at all well, but generally speaking you don't want to add methods to objects directly, rather to add them to a class and then instances of the class will see them automatically. Are you doing things differently intentionally?

Comment: @Blckknght, It is intentional, some objects will have this method and others not :\

Comment: Well, there's your problem. Don't do that. As to what is the correct way to do it, that can only be answered when you have told us what you are trying to solve.

Comment: @LennartRegebro, Basically what I want is to create a method or function in CPython and add as attribute. But if it's to don't do that, I will try another solution :(

Comment: No, that's what you THINK you want. You probably don't want that at all. That's why I asked what problem you are trying to solve, a question you completely ignored. Anyway: You can probably make a CPython *function* instead, that takes an object as an argument.

Comment: @LennartRegebro, "... make a CPython function instead...". The problem is that this function would be useless for most of the same type objects. The method I wanted would be called "get_orig_index(self, index)." But it would be necessary only in a very specific case.

Comment: So, only call it on the objects that it makes sense. You still refuse to explain the problem you are trying to solve, and then you won't get very good answers. That's not a very clever way to use other peoples time.

Comment: @LennartRegebro, If I explain everything I'm trying to do. It would be a lot, and would change the focus.
- I'm creating a bvhtree module in python using callbacks with userdatas with trees that may have elements(leaves) with different index.
- Within the callback I want to get the original index of these elements(leaves).
- The userdata is a new type of object whit attributes: `{__dict__, tree, coords, (get_orig_index)}`.
- `get_orig_index` should be optional.

Comment: The problem of my initial solution is that when you close the program with python. Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. And this is no problem with refcount

Comment: You can also have it return None if there is no orig_index. In no case does it make sense to attach methods to objects arbitrarily. And calling those methods after the object has been deleted is pretty obviously gonna crash. Your attemped solution just isn't the right one, you need to back up one step.

Comment: I'm accepting the return None solution now. Add methods without suffering CRASHs has been more a challenge than a solution.

Thanks @LennartRegebro